# Why does nearest_hostname loadbalancing configuration not work in ClickHouse?

Tags: configuration, load-balancing, clickhouse

I wrote something like this in my configuration file

```
<yandex>
  <remote_servers>
    <clickhouse>
      <shard>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
        <replica>
          <host>s00-r00.clickhouse.xxx.net</host>
          <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
        <replica>
          <host>s00-r01.clickhouse.xxx.net</host>
          <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
      </shard>
      <shard>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
        <replica>
          <host>s01-r00.clickhouse.xxx.net</host>
          <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
        <replica>
          <host>s01-r01.clickhouse.xxx.net</host>
          <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
      </shard>
    </clickhouse>
  </remote_servers>
</yandex>
```

And my load_balancing configuration was `nearest_hostname`.

I created a table on cluster clickhouse and a distributed table on it.

I submited a global query on this distributed table on the s00-r00 machine, and it was expected that local queries should be executed on the s00-r00 and s01-r00 machines.

But by monitoring several query tests, in addition to s00-r00 machine, I was able to see it executed in both s01-r00 and s01-r01 at different times.

If my understanding is correct, the hostname in my configuration should conform to the [document description](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#load_balancing-nearest_hostname) of `nearest_hostname`.
Why didn't it work?

Or is the hostname identified by this `nearest_hostname` configuration not the hostname configured in `<remote_servers><clickhouse><shard><replica>`, but something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small number of requests (<1%) need to be executed at s01-r01 to check it availability and gather error statistics of all replicas in other shards.

Another reason: at some point in time the number of errors at far replica   could became lower than at near replica.

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#load_balancing-nearest_hostname

*The number of errors is counted for each replica. Every 5 minutes, the number of errors is integrally divided by 2. Thus, the number of errors is calculated for a recent time with exponential smoothing. If there is one replica with a minimal number of errors (i.e. errors occurred recently on the other replicas), the query is sent to it. If there are multiple replicas with the same minimal number of errors, the query is sent to the replica with a host name that is most similar to the server's host name in the config file (for the number of different characters in identical positions, up to the minimum length of both host names).*

I use nearest_hostname and it works as expected except that the distance  formula itself is tricky and calculates distance as a number of different letters.

*s00-r00 -> s01-r00 (distance 1)*

*s00-r00 -> s01-r01 (distance 2)*

*dcx01 --> dcx12  (distance 2)*

*dcx01 --> dcy01  (distance 1)*

Comment: Thanks! guess I need to do more test.

Comment: can you please help me with another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698597/how-to-solve-clickhouse-deadlock 
It kept me from releasing the service

Comment: Hi! Can you tell what does the `error` exactly mean when load balancing? Does `error` refer to the exceptions thrown from queries? Or something else?